# R, select rows according to the rank of a certain column

Tags: r

I have a R dataframe like this below,

```
name score
marry 98
marry 77
marry 87
marry 96
mark 99
mark 44
mark 79
john 87
john 77
```

For each of the name, I want to select the rows with the highest 2 score, which should be,

```
name score
marry 98
marry 96
mark 99
mark 79
john 87
john 77
```

Could anyone help?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a possible base approach:

```
mydf[with(mydf, ave(-score, name, FUN = order)) %in% c(1, 2), ]
#    name score
# 1 marry    98
# 4 marry    96
# 5  mark    99
# 7  mark    79
# 8  john    87
# 9  john    77
```

---

For the curious, on timings--here's a small test...

Two sample datasets, both 1M rows, two columns, but one with only 1000 possible values for "name" and the other with 10000 possible values.

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(
  name = sample(1000, 1000000, TRUE),
  score = sample(0:100, 1000000, TRUE)
)
df2 <- data.frame(
  name = sample(10000, 1000000, TRUE),
  score = sample(0:100, 1000000, TRUE)
)
```

The functions to benchmark--I'll try to add "dplyr" later after I reinstall it.

```
fun1 <- function(mydf) {
  mydf[with(mydf, ave(-score, name, FUN = order)) %in% c(1, 2), ]
}

fun2 <- function(mydf) {
  as.data.table(mydf)[order(-score), .SD[1:2], by=name]
}

fun3 <- function(mydf) {
  df <- as.data.table(mydf)
  setorder(df, -score)[, head(.SD, 2), by = name]
}
```

The benchmarking.

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun1(df1), fun2(df1), fun3(df1), 
               fun1(df2), fun2(df2), fun3(df2), times = 20)
# Unit: milliseconds
#       expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
#  fun1(df1)  502.76809  513.98317  569.47883  597.90488  603.34458  686.4302    20
#  fun2(df1)  733.12544  741.18777  796.67106  822.60824  828.88449  839.3837    20
#  fun3(df1)   87.80581   93.07012   95.34281   95.56374   97.49608  101.7991    20
#  fun1(df2)  672.60241  764.10237  764.60365  772.33959  780.14679  799.3505    20
#  fun2(df2) 6338.14881 6360.42621 6407.66675 6412.99278 6451.75626 6479.2681    20
#  fun3(df2)  354.24119  366.47396  382.58666  369.78597  374.01897  468.9197    20
```

Comment: (+1), but I don't like this `as.data.table` of yours. I would assume `setDT` would be more efficient (but I may be wrong because `df` didn't exists previously). I also think you should name the functions by their authors so it will be clear who's the winner ;)

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I don't think it makes much of a difference. It's either that or using `copy` since we are really interested in testing how the ordering is handled (unless I'm approaching the benchmarking incorrectly).

Comment: Ok, atleast make it one line, something like `setorder(as.data.table(mydf), -score)[, head(.SD, 2), by = name]`

Comment: @Ananda Mahto I updated with the benchmarks including `dplyr`

Answer (score 5):

Here's another `data.table` approach using the new `setorder` function (order by reference)

```
library(data.table) # 1.9.4+
setorder(setDT(df), -score)[, head(.SD, 2), by = name]
#     name score
# 1:  mark    99
# 2:  mark    79
# 3: marry    98
# 4: marry    96
# 5:  john    87
# 6:  john    77
```

Comment: +1 Just curious, do you know if this is faster than the one I posted?

Comment: @akrun, of course it is. `setorder` supposed to be much more efficient. Unless `:` beats `head`, which would be interesting to check

Comment: @akrun, no offence, but my `ave` solution is faster than your "data.table" one, at least up to ~ 1M rows, but David's is consistently  the fastest.

Comment: @akrun, it probably also depends on the number of unique "name" values and so on--`setorder` is the way to go with this. David, +1

Comment: @akrun, David, I added some benchmarks to my answer.

Comment: @Ananda Mahto If you change `.SD[1:2]` to `head(.SD,2)`, will it make any difference? The timings on `df2` is surprising.

Comment: @akrun, `data.table:::fastorder` is (guess what) faster than `order`. I don't think `head` would make a significant difference.

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

```
 devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")
 library(dplyr)


 df %>% 
      group_by(name) %>% 
      arrange(desc(score)) %>%
       slice(1:2)

 #     name score
 #1  john    87
 #2  john    77
 #3  mark    99
 #4  mark    79
 #5 marry    98
 #6 marry    96
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[order(-score), .SD[1:2], by=name]
 #      name score
 #1:  mark    99
 #2:  mark    79
 #3: marry    98
 #4: marry    96
 #5:  john    87
 #6:  john    77
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("marry", "marry", "marry", "marry", "mark", 
   "mark", "mark", "john", "john"), score = c(98L, 77L, 87L, 96L, 
   99L, 44L, 79L, 87L, 77L)), .Names = c("name", "score"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -9L))
```

#### Benchmarks

Included `dplyr` and `base R` methods by @Richard Scriven.  Created two datasets, 1) Same as generated by @Ananda Mahto's 2nd dataset, 2) 50x bigger.

- Data

  ```
  set.seed(1) #similar dataset as created by @Ananda Mahto
  dfAM <- data.frame(
              name = sample(10000, 1000000, TRUE),
              score = sample(0:100, 1000000, TRUE)
              )


  set.seed(1)
  df2 <- data.frame(
               name = sample(10000, 50*1000000, TRUE),
               score = sample(0:100, 50*1000000, TRUE)
              )
  ```
- Functions

  ```
    aMahto <- function(mydf) {mydf[with(mydf, 
               ave(-score, name, FUN = order)) %in% c(1, 2), ]
             }

    akrun1 <- function(mydf) {setDT(mydf)[order(-score), .SD[1:2], by=name] }
    akrun2 <- function(mydf) {setDT(mydf)[order(-score), head(.SD,2), by=name] }
    dArenburg <- function(mydf){ setorder(setDT(mydf), -score)[,
                                              head(.SD,2), by=name]}
    akrun3 <- function(mydf) { mydf %>% group_by(name) %>% 
                                 arrange(desc(score)) %>% slice(1:2) }


    rScriven1 <- function(mydf) {sapply(split(mydf$score, mydf$name),
                                         function(x) tail(sort(x), 2))}
    rScriven2 <- function(mydf) {stack(lapply(split(mydf$score, mydf$name),
                                          function(x) tail(sort(x), 2)))}
  ```
- Benchmarks
  Run the benchmarks for each dataset separately.

  ```
    library(microbenchmark)
    microbenchmark(aMahto(dfAM), akrun1(dfAM), akrun2(dfAM), akrun3(dfAM),
                  dArenburg(dfAM), rScriven1(dfAM), rScriven2(dfAM), times=20L)
     Unit: milliseconds
           expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq
     aMahto(dfAM)  278.11839  283.82547  293.16843  285.45645  298.77528
     akrun1(dfAM) 2900.86528 2923.94839 2953.00178 2942.73172 2965.85868
     akrun2(dfAM)  189.93849  195.05222  202.30496  196.51019  207.73886
     akrun3(dfAM)   56.75191   57.14967   58.04335   57.32627   57.63047
  dArenburg(dfAM)  161.87583  166.64286  171.67832  168.24355  170.14656
  rScriven1(dfAM)  694.22503  701.85554  717.92201  713.15419  727.84196
  rScriven2(dfAM)  712.84676  728.75839  744.07167  738.74824  759.88312
          max neval
    335.04468    20
   3113.54895    20
    250.09765    20
     66.67198    20
    228.44948    20
    777.78973    20
    797.85850    20
  ```

On the bigger dataset, @David Arenburg's method is the `Winner`.

```
    microbenchmark(aMahto(df2), akrun1(df2), akrun2(df2), akrun3(df2), 
                 dArenburg(df2), rScriven1(df2), rScriven2(df2), times=40L)
    Unit: seconds
            expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max
     aMahto(df2) 11.830111 12.027325 12.273881 12.213140 12.533628 13.196659
     akrun1(df2)  6.672874  6.890442  7.018749  6.956716  7.128060  7.542047
     akrun2(df2)  3.794502  3.829567  3.860565  3.847690  3.869065  4.143381
     akrun3(df2)  3.687974  3.725867  3.801861  3.743973  3.933935  4.102295
  dArenburg(df2)  1.531356  1.598570  1.647648  1.618573  1.640258  2.716042
  rScriven1(df2)  6.370144  6.573998  6.685313  6.616246  6.820830  7.118827
  rScriven2(df2)  6.551911  6.628134  6.743644  6.724310  6.867090  7.091750
     neval
      40
      40
      40
      40
      40
      40
      40
```

Comment: +1 on the "data.table" approach. I was posting the base R equivalent as you were posting this, I guess :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's a different output, but how about this so that the names aren't repeated.

```
sapply(split(df$score, df$name), function(x) tail(sort(x), 2))
#      john mark marry
# [1,]   77   79    96
# [2,]   87   99    98
```

As suggested by Ananda Mahto, you could also use `stack` with `lapply`

```
stack(lapply(split(df$score, df$name), function(x) tail(sort(x), 2)))
#   values   ind
# 1     77  john
# 2     87  john
# 3     79  mark
# 4     99  mark
# 5     96 marry
# 6     98 marry
```

Comment: +1, but you might want to consider `lapply` instead of `sapply`. It's faster, and it will let you do: `stack(lapply(split(df$score, df$name), function(x) tail(sort(x), 2)))`.

Comment: It's not as fast as `unlist`, but it should be faster than `simplify2array`.